# Safari SSL certificate issue and external javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, safari, birt

My site is running on SSL. On one of the pages I am calling an external javascript required for integration of Birt iHub into our application. The iHub application is running separately on of o our servers and javascript also resided in same application. Now when I try to acces the javascript without SSL it is blocked as my site is running on SSL. So I also put the iHub app on SSL so tha my website communcate with javascript over SSL. Now it works fine for both Chrome, Firefox and IE but in case of Safari it worked for few days then suddely an SSL error shows up. I have delete the SSL certificates from cache and the access the site again and IT worked again but afeter some days same issue occurs. AndI have to delte it again to make it work.

Can anyone tell me whay this is happening and what could be done to avoid this

Comment: What is the SSL error from Safari that is coming up?

Comment: No error is coming up in console atleast. Its just blocking the access to the javascript file. What other place do I have to look for SSL error.